# How to make program follow order of an input instead of the order of the code typed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
t = input('Enter a symbol to use for your letter:')
message = input('Enter a message:').upper()


if 'F' in message:
    print(f"{t}"f"{t}"f"{t}"f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
          f"{t}"f'{t}'"\n"
          f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
          f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
          f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
          f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
          f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
          "               ")
if 'H' in message:
        for row in range(7):
            for col in range(5):
               if col ==0 or col ==4 or (row==3 and (col>0 and col<4)):
                    print(f'{t}', end="")
                else:
                    print(end=" ")
            print()
```

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to input a symbol, number, letter, etc. of their choice and input a message and have the code print the message in that specific symbol, number, letter. The code above prints out the letters F and H (still a work in progress), the problem is that it doesn't follow the order of the input and instead follows the order of the code that was typed. For example (code for letter F is on top and H on the bottom), when I type FH everything runs fine, but when I type HF it still prints out FH in the symbols. How do I code it so it does both in the order that I put them in?

Comment: You could write functions for each letter, then iterate your input character-by-character and call the appropriate function for each character.

Comment: Removed Python2.7 tag as this is appears to Python3 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = input('Enter a symbol to use for your letter:')
message = input('Enter a message:')

for m in message:
    if m == 'F':
        print('do F stuff')
    if m == 'H':
        print('do H stuff')
```

You can cycle over the message and do the stuff you need, for every char.

Answer (score 0):

Following `@Mike Scotty`'s comment idea. Define the following function

```
def letter_handling(letter):
    if letter=='F':
        #Code here
    elif letter=='H':
        #Code here
    ....
```

You can add as many letters as you like and in any order...

Then, just set your code to:

```
t = input('Enter a symbol to use for your letter:')
message = input('Enter a message:').upper()

for letter in message:
    letter_handling(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your print code inside a function as follows:

```py
def printMessage(char , message):

    if 'F' == char:
        print(f"{t}"f"{t}"f"{t}"f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
              f"{t}"f'{t}'"\n"
              f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
              f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
              f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
              f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
              f'{t}'f'{t}'"\n"
              "               ")
    elif 'H' == char:
            for row in range(7):
                for col in range(5):
                   if col ==0 or col ==4 or (row==3 and (col>0 and col<4)):
                        print(f'{t}', end="")
                   else:
                        print(end=" ")
                print()
```

and then you can iterate in your `message` text and make a print for every letter in order that the user entered.

```py
for char in message:
    printMessage(char , t)
```